# Migrate the "Site FAQ" link to Meta StackOverflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

Since we all agree that [**Meta Is Murder**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001282.html), maybe it is time to migrate the "Site FAQ" link located to the bottom of a website's [faq link](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to point to meta.stackoverflow.com ?

Right now, anyone looking at that page and posting a `so-faq` gets his/her question closed and migrated here by the community. Might as well point them to the right place...

So, this proposal is to:

- Add four tags to the "required" list of Meta StackOverflow, namely:

  - **[`faq`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)** : FAQ related to any of the SO family websites
  - **[`faq + stackoverflow`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+stackoverflow)** : FAQ related to Stack Overflow only
  - **[`faq + serverfault`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+serverfault)** : FAQ related to Server Fault only
  - **[`faq + superuser`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+superuser)** : FAQ related to Super User only
- Replace the "Site FAQ" link to point to a search page searching for the proper tags, ie.: **[`faq + stackoverflow`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+stackoverflow)** for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The convention will be to use `faq + stackoverflow` for faq entries that pertain to stackoverflow, and similar tags for the rest of the sites. I've edited your question to make this clear to other people.

Comment: **@Kyle Cronin:** Thanks, I've done further edits for my last point in my proposal.

Comment: What's up with your search links? Why this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-%28serverfault%20superuser%29%20faq%20or%20%28faq%20stackoverflow%29 instead of this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+stackoverflow ?

Comment: **@Kyle Cronin:** I'm trying to make in include all questions tagged `faq` alone, and all questions tagged `faq + stackoverflow` in the same search so that general and specific posts are listed in the same search.

Comment: There is a problem with the links.

Comment: **@Brad Gilbert:** What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It still needs to point to some kind of FAQ, so they can directly find their answers.

Comment: `so-faq`, `sf-faq`, `su-faq`, `faq` (general) tags here would work nicely.

Comment: That assumes they know how to work the tags, since a lot of new people would be looking for the FAQ, they may not have that level of knowledge yet.  They need a simple link (like we have now) that takes them to a FAQ (which could be done better (i.e. more organized, more information)).

Comment: **@Lance Roberts:** The link itself would link to meta.stackoverflow.com, in a search page for `[so-faq] [faq]` for example. Same as how the link is implemented currently.

Comment: Yes, that would work fine.